# Integral with 'reset'

Tags: integration

I am trying to mathify the following algorithm description:

> The algorithm iterates over the elements in the sequence $(f_1, ..., f_n)$, calculating the heuristic function $h(f_k, f_{k+1})$ for each step. The function value is summed, and whenever the sum becomes greater than the threshold $\tau_t$ the element $f_k$ is appended to the output **and $\tau_t$ is subtracted from the sum**.

I can express everything up to the bold part but I do not know any expression for the last part, that is short and understandable by most readers.

An example of what I would like:

$$\begin{align}
H(f) &= \sum\limits_{x\in f}\left\{\begin{aligned}
\hspace{0pt}h(x, x_{next}) -\tau_t\hspace{10pt}if \hspace{10pt}condition\\
\hspace{0pt}h(x, x_{next})\hspace{30pt}otherwise\end{aligned}
\right.
\\
h(x, x_{next}) &= \sqrt{\left(x-x_{next}\right)^2}
\end{align}
$$

It seems like this should be easily expressable, but I can't find a way. I could define it as a recursive function, but that's obfuscating the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$I_f(k) := \sum_{i=1}^{k} h(f_i, f_{i+1})$$
Then
$$H(f)_k = f_{\max \{ i \mid I_f(i) \le k \tau_t \}} \qquad \text{for } k \le \lfloor I_f(n) / \tau_t \rfloor$$
Where $H(f)_k$ is the $k$-th output, i.e. $H(f)$ is a sequence of length $\le n$.

Comment: Very nice! Clearly, it makes more sense to define the function not in terms of heuristic value but in terms of output values. Thank you.